# Office 365 Rest API - Retrieving plain text Email

Tags: email, office365, exchangewebservices, plaintext

Is there currently anyway to with the Office 365 Rest APIs to retrieve the plain text part of an email message?

From the API documents it states that the 'Body' object contains the 'ContentType' field which can either be *Text* or *HTML*. https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#ItemBody

However whenever a multipart (HTML + plain text) message is retrieved the API only ever returns the HTML part as shown bellow:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "",
  "@odata.id": "",
  "Id": "",
  "Subject": "Test message",
  "BodyPreview": "This is the body",
  "Body": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n</head>\r\n<body style=\"word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-size: 14px; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;\">\r\n<div>This is the body</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"
  },
  "UniqueBody": {
    "ContentType": "HTML",
    "Content": "<html><body><div>\r\n<div><font face=\"Calibri,sans-serif\" size=\"2\" color=\"black\"><span style=\"font-size:14px;\">\r\n<div>This is the body</div>\r\n</span></font></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body></html>"
  },
  "HasAttachments": false,
  "Sender": {
    "EmailAddress": {
        "Address": "",
        "Name": "Nick Maher"
    }
  },
  "DateTimeReceived": "2015-02-10T14:39:22Z",
  "DateTimeSent": "2015-02-10T14:39:21Z"
}
```

Is there anyway of getting the plain text part. Possibly an OData query?

Many thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. I can provide this feedback to our developers. Can you give me some background on why you need this ability? Not that I'm questioning, it's just helpful to have some context. :)

Comment: Hi Jason, I want to strip out any quoted reply text. This is much easier using the plain text as the quoted text lines are almost always prepended by a '>' character. I was hoping to use this library: https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser.

I think for a multipart email it would be nice to return a list for the 'Body' field with each part as its own object

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'll include this information in the feedback.

Comment: Hi Jason, do you know if any progress has been on adding this functionality to the O365 API? It would be very useful for when using the API to process and parse the text of incoming mail messages - as currently if the messages are in HTML format it is very difficult to extract just the reply text from the email and ignore everything else. Thanks.

Comment: No progress that I'm aware of. You could add a suggestion on [UserVoice](http://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131775-outlook-apis) for it so folks can vote it up :)

Comment: @JasonJohnston After two years. It looks like this feature still not available. Api docs say "The message body can be either HTML or text. " is there anyway to explicitly request plain text email body ?

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since it is supported now to specify the desired format, refer [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) for a details

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Vadim. Angelgolfer's answer below should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to give an update - you can now use the Microsoft Graph REST API to get messages returned in text format.

Note that this feature is currently in preview only. In general, we recommend using preview features only in non-production apps, as they may change without notice.

I listed an example below. The related documentation for Microsoft Graph - [Get](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/message_get) and [List](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_messages) messages - will be updated within the next day.

This example shows how to use a Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text" header to get the body and uniqueBody of the specified message in text format.

```
Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages('AAMkAGI1AAAoZCfHAAA=')?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,uniqueBody
```

Here is the response. Note: The response includes a Preference-Applied: outlook.body-content-type header to acknowledge the Prefer: outlook.body-content-type request header.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json
Preference-Applied: outlook.body-content-type="text"
Content-length: 1550

{
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('cd209b0b-3f83-4c35-82d2-d88a61820480')/messages(subject,body,bodyPreview,uniqueBody)/$entity",
    "@odata.etag":"W/\"CQAAABYAAABmWdbhEgBXTophjCWt81m9AAAoZYj4\"",
    "id":"AAMkAGI1AAAoZCfHAAA=",
    "subject":"Welcome to our group!",
    "bodyPreview":"Welcome to our group, Dana! Hope you will enjoy working with us !\r\n\r\nWould you like to choose a day for our orientation from the available times below:\r\n\r\n\r\nDate\r\n        Time\r\n\r\nApril 14, 2017\r\n        1-3pm\r\n\r\nApril 21, 2017\r\n        10-12noon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nTh",
    "body":{
        "contentType":"text",
        "content":"Welcome to our group, Dana! Hope you will enjoy working with us [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] !\r\n\r\nWould you like to choose a day for our orientation from the available times below:\r\n\r\n\r\nDate\r\n        Time\r\n\r\nApril 14, 2017\r\n        1-3pm\r\n\r\nApril 21, 2017\r\n        10-12noon\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks!\r\n\r\n"
    },
    "uniqueBody":{
        "contentType":"text",
        "content":"Welcome to our group, Dana! Hope you will enjoy working with us [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] [\ud83d\ude0a] !\r\nWould you like to choose a day for our orientation from the available times below:\r\n\r\nDate\r\n        Time\r\n\r\nApril 14, 2017\r\n        1-3pm\r\n\r\nApril 21, 2017\r\n        10-12noon\r\n\r\n\r\nThanks!\r\n"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Old thread, I know, but is there any chance that this parameter could be expanded so that the unique body could optionally be the only one returned as plain text, leaving the full body as html? This would be useful in my production environment as we currently get EWS to return the unique body in plain text for display in one place, but the full html of the email including quoting elsewhere.

Comment: @Angelgolfer-ms can you tell me how can I add this `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"` to my header? I'm using node-outlook