# Can Office 365 REST API send an email with both plain text and HTML body?

Tags: office365, office365api

I'm looking at the API docs, and it looks like you can specify only one `Body` in a `Message`.

Sending a message:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#SendMessages

The `Message` type:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#MessageResource

Is it possible to do something like a multi-part message with plain text and HTML?

Ultimately I'm looking to send this message with an attached calendar meeting invitation, but that's another topic.

Comment: What does it even mean to have a message in both Text and HTML? How do you even want clients to be able to render this?

Comment: @Yogesh It is a very standard practice to have an email in both text and HTML. The client renders the one you prefer.

Comment: Apparently you want to simply attach an HTML file to a text email?

Comment: @GSerg I don't think the attachment is the same. I think I want `Content-Type: multipart/alternative; ...` on the main body message, and then the 2 parts with content types `text/plain` and `text/html`

Comment: Apparently [it's not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28436361/11683).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can Office 365 REST API send an email with both plain text and HTML body?

No, you will use REST point to set one type of the body or another.

> Is it possible to do something like a multi-part message with plain text and HTML?

This will be done for you by Exchange environment when message will be converted to MIME on send. Exchange will generate "multipart/alternative" parts of the MIME and set appropriate plain text and HTML for the content you set with your REST call. For example if you set "HTML" body via rest request, the outgoing MIME will have HTML part, as you set it, and alternative "plaintext" part, which will be generated by Exchange MIME converter as strip off version to bare text of your HTML; and vise versa.

Please note we are not discussing "multipart/mixed" parts which related to attachments of the message. This is only about alternative parts for the body of the message.

Finally, look at the Microsoft Outlook application. This is nothing else as yet another client for Exchange environment. You may compose message as plain text or choose to compose it as RTF/HTML, but never both. The alternative part will be generated by [Exchange MIME converter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232174%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as the part of Message -> MIME conversion and MIME will have alternative parts of the same body.

At the end I am mot sure if I answered on your question, because by the comments it looks like you know what is "multipart/alternative" and how it's different from "multipart/mixed".

Comment: I'd say you answered it. That's helpful. And good to know that Outlook is just another client to these same APIs. Otherwise I might have gone down some rabbit hole like writing a native Windows app to control the Outlook application in an attempt to get more features than the REST APIs.

Comment: @RobN Well, Outlook is yet another client to Exchange, but it doesn't use REST indeed. REST is the public API for 3rd party applications. Outlook (modern one) itself uses [MAPI over HTTP](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2014/05/09/outlook-connectivity-with-mapi-over-http/). Over here I tried to deliver the point that what ever does Exchange before sending the Message object to the wild will be valid for any client and API. Glad it clarify things for you.

Comment: Ah, okay. Can I use MAPI too or is private? The reason I ask is that I need to create some rich text emails with calendar invites. I want to make sure my program can do anything that users in Outlook can do. In the past, this was a problem, but I haven't really gotten into testing the Office 365 REST APIs yet.

Comment: You right, this is private interface. What is available for 3rd party apps: REST, EWS (almost the same, SOAP version), Office Graph API and add-in Outlook extensibility with MAPI (VSTO/COM) or Office Add-ins. A lot of choices. This may be helpful for you to read through: [Selecting an API or technology for developing solutions for Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900714.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)