# Is it possible to create/send a message with both text/plain and text/html bodies using MAIL REST API?

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi

Looking at the documentation of REST API and outlook client library it seems the REST API only support creating/sending TEXT or HTML body in the request but not both.

Would be nice if someone can confirm this. Does the API provide a way to encode HTML and plain text bodies?

Comment: Please see this Question and Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723930/can-office-365-rest-api-send-an-email-with-both-plain-text-and-html-body/43746289#43746289

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the API doesn't support this. You set either one or the other, and the server creates an equivalent "other" for clients that support/request it.