# Microsoft Graph - Send email with text and html bodies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

How can I send a message using **Microsoft Graph** that would have both, *text* **AND** *html* bodies?

Comment: I know how to send a message that has text OR html body, but I would like to send a message that has both types of bodies. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean exaclty? In the same email body?

Comment: @NicoBleiler - No. In the same message, two alternative bodies.

Comment: Have you looked into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/itembody?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity - How is that helpful?

Answer (score -1):

For those finding this message sometime later, pulling your hair out trying to understand why Microsoft didn't make this clear in the documentation, see this post: [Can Office 365 REST API send an email with both plain text and HTML body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723930/can-office-365-rest-api-send-an-email-with-both-plain-text-and-html-body)

I've confirmed this on my end - once the graph API request is made, the Exchange server does, in fact, strip the HTML characters, creates a multipart message (with boundaries) and delivers in the appropriate format.

In my case, I only needed to set the following:

```
body.contentType = BodyType.HTML;
body.content = myCustomEmailObject.getHtml();
```

Here's an example of what the raw response (email source) looks like in gmail:

```
--_000_CO6PR14MB42581EA88B5BE054EFE62113CF449CO6PR14MB4258namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

This is the content
And this is a new line...

--_000_CO6PR14MB42581EA88B5BE054EFE62113CF449CO6PR14MB4258namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii"=
>
</head>
<body>
<b>This is the content</b><br>
And this is a new line...
</body>
</html>

--_000_CO6PR14MB42581EA88B5BE054EFE62113CF449CO6PR14MB4258namp_--
```