# MIcrosoft API get Calendar Event description and show it appropriately

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

In my React project, I made an Axios call to populate a Calendar Event List taking data from Microsoft Outlook Calendar (using Microsoft API). The result is the following
[image]

As you can see only event description give me a problem. Indeed to show the event description it shows me an HTML string without the event detail.

I read that I have to put in the header of my request `Content-type:text`, but I tried and It doesn't work.  How I can solve that? This is my Axios Request

```
getEvents(startDate, endDate, accessToken) {
    const startDateString = startDate.toISOString();
    const endDateString = endDate.toISOString();
    axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${USER_PUBLIC_ID}/calendarview?startdatetime=${startDateString}&enddatetime=${endDateString}&orderby=start/dateTime`,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      },
    ).then(response => this.setEvents(response.data.value))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.response);
      });
  }
```

Comment: here there is a topic  similar, but I don't know how to apply that solution with Axios:     
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436361/office-365-rest-api-retrieving-plain-text-email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that matter `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"` header needs to be specified.

[According to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations):

> To specify the desired format to be returned in the **Body** and
>   **UniqueBody** properties in a GET request, use the `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type` header:
>
> - Specify `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"` to get a message    body returned in text format.
> - Specify `Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="html"`, or just skip the    header, to return the message body in HTML format.

**Example**

```
getEvents(startDate, endDate, accessToken) {
    const startDateString = startDate.toISOString();
    const endDateString = endDate.toISOString();
    return axios.get(
      `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${USER_PUBLIC_ID}/calendarview?startdatetime=${startDateString}&enddatetime=${endDateString}&orderby=start/dateTime`,
      {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Prefer' : 'outlook.body-content-type="text"'
        }
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: The response is ok, I mean the the body content type is text as in the header specification...but the response.body.content is an empty string, if indeed i don't write in the header 'Prefer' : 'outlook.body-content-type="text"', indeed of an empty string I have:  <html><head><meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Exchange Server">
↵<!-- converted from text -->
↵<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>
↵<body>
↵<font size="2"><span style="font-size:11pt;"><div class="PlainText">&nbsp;</div></span></font>
↵</body

Comment: Maybe there is a way to stop Microsoft Exchange from automatically converting to text? And if yes I have to set something on the server or I it is something that I can do also with the code?

Comment: I found out the the problem was not the code bu just a setting of privilege in Microsoft Outlook, so now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give axios a config object. Currently, you are using the get property, that is why your code doesn't work currently:

```
axios({
url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${USER_PUBLIC_ID}/calendarview?startdatetime=${startDateString}&enddatetime=${endDateString}&orderby=start/dateTime`,
method: "GET",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          "Content-type": "text"
        },
})
```

You can read more here: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: I tried but the JSON response is  the same: 

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/evBxn.png

I think that the problem is that the body contentType is in html, indeed should be text. In the link that i put in the comment one guy suggest to add 

> Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"

But I don't understand in my case, with Axios, how I should apply that solution

Comment: I edited my answer and added a custom header. You can use this syntax to add headers. Just make sure that the spelling is correct and use quotes for properties with hypens.

Comment: I edited my file, but it doesn't work :( in the response it is still "body: {contentType: "html"}"

Comment: I edited the header in this way:  `code headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        Prefer: 'outlook.body-content-type="text"',
      },` and now in the json response I have contentType: "text", but now the description  in the component doesn't have a string as in the image i post in my question, but it is empty

Comment: Try it like this: ```code headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken}, Prefer: "outlook.body-content-type": "text", }``` or like this:
```code headers: { Authorization: Bearer ${accessToken}, Prefer: outlook: { "body-content-type": "text" } }```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is the same: I mean, now adding that "Prefer etc. etc." it works, because in the json response body.contenType if finally text, but it's like as the event doens't have a description, but it has. I try the same query with Micrososft Graph Explorer with a Sample calendar and there it work: the Json file in body.content ha a string with the description of the event...Could be maybe  "Microsoft Exchange Server" the problem? OR some rule to be setting up?